# When creating a publisher via `vsce` I get a 401

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I am running this command to create a VSCode publisher:

```
 vsce create-publisher cprev
```

but I am getting this 401 error:

[my shell showing the 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ec4Y.png)

I have a personal token created like so:

[the azure devops console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6CS7.png)

anyone know why I am getting a 401? Is there some way to debug it, to get a more specific message?

Comment: "Note: Alternatively, create your publisher in the Marketplace publisher management page and log in through vsce, as described in the next section." https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#create-a-publisher

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> One easy mistake to make when creating the PAT (Personal Access Token)
>   is to  **not select all accessible accounts** in the Accounts field
>   drop-down (instead selecting a specific account). You should also set
>   the Authorized Scopes to All scopes for the publish to work。

[image]

Please set Organization in drop down list with  **All accessible organizations**.

More details pleas take a look at this similar issue here:  [vsce create-publisher returns 401](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/11)

Comment: Thx, it really helped :) just to mention that selecting All accessible organizations without Full access could solve the problem

Comment: thanks, had the same issue, even though there was only 1 organization in my list, selecting all worked, where the single organization did not.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by making sure that my `Personal Access Token` has the following settings:

- **Scopes > "Custom defined"**

  - **Marketplace > [x] Manage**

[image]

[Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#get-a-personal-access-token)